# root executed find command slowing down my server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I'm not sure how the `find` commands are executed, there seems to be some indication that it is a CRON job but it is not one I've created.

I believe these find commands are slowing down my server causing access to webpages extremely difficult.

How can I track what is executing these `find` processes?

Below is a ps -aux output.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  24332   852 ?        Ss   Dec05   0:00 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:09 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 [migration/0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 [migration/1]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:08 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 [watchdog/1]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec05   0:00 [cpuset]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec05   0:00 [khelper]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec05   0:00 [netns]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:01 [kworker/u:1]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 [sync_supers]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 [bdi-default]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec05   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec05   0:00 [kblockd]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec05   0:00 [ata_sff]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 [khubd]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec05   0:00 [md]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        27  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   3:21 [kswapd0]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Dec05   0:00 [ksmd]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Dec05   0:00 [khugepaged]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec05   0:00 [crypto]
root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec05   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 [kworker/u:2]
root        63  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec05   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root       179  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec05   0:00 [ttm_swap]
root       227  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   1:15 [jbd2/sda1-8]
root       228  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec05   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       356  0.0  0.0  17232   160 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
103        358  0.0  0.0  23816   288 ?        Ss   Dec05   0:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork --activation=upstart
syslog     362  0.0  0.0 249468   980 ?        Sl   Dec05   0:06 rsyslogd -c5
root       364  0.0  0.0  21664   296 ?        Ss   Dec05   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       442  0.0  0.0  21660   240 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       443  0.0  0.0  21660   200 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       459  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec05   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       502  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec05   0:00 [edac-poller]
root       561  0.0  0.0  50036   628 ?        Ss   Dec05   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root       592  0.0  0.0  23436   108 ?        Ss   Dec05   0:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd
root       696  0.0  0.0  15188     4 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
root       712  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec05   0:03 [flush-8:0]
root       977  0.0  0.0  15784   296 tty4     Ss+  Dec05   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root       980  0.0  0.0  15784   296 tty5     Ss+  Dec05   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
root       984  0.0  0.0  15784   296 tty2     Ss+  Dec05   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root       985  0.0  0.0  15784   296 tty3     Ss+  Dec05   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root       990  0.0  0.0  15784   296 tty6     Ss+  Dec05   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
root      1002  0.0  0.0  17432   564 ?        Ss   Dec05   0:00 /usr/sbin/dovecot -F -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
root      1007  0.0  0.0  19112   404 ?        Ss   Dec05   0:00 cron
daemon    1008  0.0  0.0  16908   124 ?        Ss   Dec05   0:00 atd
root      1009  0.0  0.0  15980   380 ?        Ss   Dec05   0:05 /usr/sbin/irqbalance
mysql     1028  1.3  7.3 1340860 150816 ?      Ssl  Dec05  17:34 /usr/sbin/mysqld
dovecot   1035  0.0  0.0   8952   432 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 dovecot/anvil
root      1036  0.0  0.0   9076   408 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 dovecot/log
amavis    1075  0.0  0.0 225620  1284 ?        Ss   Dec05   0:02 amavisd (master)
postgrey  1084  0.0  0.0  66760   760 ?        Ss   Dec05   0:00 /usr/sbin/postgrey --pidfile=/var/run/postgrey.pid --daemonize --inet=10023 
amavis    1135  0.0  0.0 309096  1588 ?        S    Dec05   0:11 amavisd (ch17-avail)
amavis    1136  0.0  0.0 312976  1688 ?        S    Dec05   0:12 amavisd (ch16-avail)
root      1181  0.0  0.1 141684  2144 ?        Ss   08:56   0:07 /usr/sbin/spamd --create-prefs --max-children 5 --helper-home-dir -d --pidfile=/var/run/spamd.pid
root      1380  0.0  0.0 141684  1392 ?        S    08:57   0:00 spamd child
root      1381  0.0  0.0 141684  1456 ?        S    08:57   0:00 spamd child
clamav    1531  0.1  0.0 781976  1956 ?        Ssl  Dec05   1:50 /usr/sbin/clamd
clamav    1648  0.1  0.0  45752  1000 ?        Ss   Dec05   2:05 /usr/bin/freshclam -d --quiet
root      1672  0.0  0.0   4304   200 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 /usr/sbin/courierlogger -pid=/var/run/courier/authdaemon/pid -start /usr/lib/courier/courier-authlib/authdaemond
root      1673  0.0  0.0  19076   256 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 /usr/lib/courier/courier-authlib/authdaemond
root      1676  0.0  0.0  19076    20 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 /usr/lib/courier/courier-authlib/authdaemond
root      1677  0.0  0.0  19076    20 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 /usr/lib/courier/courier-authlib/authdaemond
root      1678  0.0  0.0  19076    20 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 /usr/lib/courier/courier-authlib/authdaemond
root      1679  0.0  0.0  19076    20 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 /usr/lib/courier/courier-authlib/authdaemond
root      1680  0.0  0.0  19076    20 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 /usr/lib/courier/courier-authlib/authdaemond
memcache  1711  0.0  0.0 323220   252 ?        Sl   Dec05   0:02 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1
opendkim  1722  0.0  0.0  96520    92 ?        Ss   Dec05   0:00 /usr/sbin/opendkim -x /etc/opendkim.conf -u opendkim -P /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
opendkim  1725  0.0  0.0 408444   712 ?        Sl   Dec05   0:01 /usr/sbin/opendkim -x /etc/opendkim.conf -u opendkim -P /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
root      1825  0.0  0.0  25108   504 ?        Ss   Dec05   0:00 /usr/lib/postfix/master
postfix   1829  0.0  0.0  27344   484 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 qmgr -l -t fifo -u
root      1862  0.0  0.0  78744   144 ?        Ss   Dec05   0:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -n 5
root      1863  0.0  0.0  78744     4 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -n 5
root      1864  0.0  0.0  78744     4 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -n 5
root      1865  0.0  0.0  78744     4 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -n 5
root      1866  0.0  0.0  78744     4 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -n 5
113       1884  0.1  1.3  90996 27624 ?        S    Dec05   1:56 /usr/sbin/tor
root      1919  0.0  0.0 381152  1160 ?        Ss   Dec05   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      1947  0.0  0.1 330876  2496 ?        Sl   Dec05   0:29 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/fail2ban-server -b -s /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
postfix   1966  0.0  0.0  37816   472 ?        S    Dec05   0:00 tlsmgr -l -t unix -u -c
root      1984  0.0  0.0  15784   296 tty1     Ss+  Dec05   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
root      3239  0.0  0.0  68836   424 ?        S    17:39   0:00 CRON
root      3279  0.0  0.0  12300   340 ?        Ss   17:39   0:00 /bin/sh -c   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
root      3380  1.8  0.1 560788  2096 ?        D    17:39   3:15 find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +24 ! -execdir fuser -s {} ; -delete
root      4875  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:02   0:34 [kworker/0:1]
www-data  5671  0.0  1.7 699052 36124 ?        Sl   19:07   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  5673  0.0  0.9 775596 20200 ?        Dl   19:07   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  5686  0.0  1.6 551216 34788 ?        Sl   19:07   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      6965  0.0  0.0  68836   648 ?        S    19:09   0:00 CRON
root      6973  0.0  0.0  12300   620 ?        Ss   19:09   0:00 /bin/sh -c   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
root      7017  2.1  0.1 558808  2060 ?        D    19:09   1:50 find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +24 ! -execdir fuser -s {} ; -delete
www-data  7039  0.0  1.0 702384 20892 ?        Sl   19:10   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7040  0.0  1.9 699804 40400 ?        Sl   19:10   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     10727  0.0  0.0  68836   408 ?        S    16:09   0:00 CRON
root     10733  0.0  0.0  12300   300 ?        Ss   16:09   0:00 /bin/sh -c   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
root     10784  2.0  0.1 563692  2140 ?        D    16:09   5:28 find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +24 ! -execdir fuser -s {} ; -delete
root     11604  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:20   0:14 [kworker/1:0]
root     13373  0.0  0.0  68836  1192 ?        S    20:09   0:00 CRON
root     13395  0.0  0.0  12300   824 ?        Ss   20:09   0:00 /bin/sh -c   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
root     13545  0.6 26.5 557356 543476 ?       D    20:09   0:10 find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +24 ! -execdir fuser -s {} ; -delete
root     16564  0.0  0.0  68836   444 ?        S    18:09   0:00 CRON
root     16623  0.0  0.0  12300   344 ?        Ss   18:09   0:00 /bin/sh -c   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
root     16733  1.6  0.1 559864  2148 ?        D    18:09   2:29 find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +24 ! -execdir fuser -s {} ; -delete
postfix  18219  0.0  0.0  27172   924 ?        S    20:19   0:00 pickup -l -t fifo -u -c -o content_filter= -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
www-data 19027  0.0  1.6 699804 33568 ?        Sl   18:22   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     19536  0.0  0.0  68836   408 ?        S    16:39   0:00 CRON
root     19576  0.0  0.0  12300   308 ?        Ss   16:39   0:00 /bin/sh -c   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
root     19755  1.5  0.1 562240  2148 ?        D    16:39   3:47 find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +24 ! -execdir fuser -s {} ; -delete
root     19979  0.0  0.1  54824  2068 ?        Ss   20:25   0:00 sshd: root@pts/0    
root     19988  0.0  0.2  20664  4220 pts/0    Ss   20:25   0:00 -bash
root     21893  0.0  0.1  54676  2096 ?        Ss   20:30   0:00 sshd: root@notty    
root     21896  0.0  0.0  12776   800 ?        Ss   20:30   0:00 /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
amavis   22005  0.0  1.4 304128 30616 ?        S    17:05   0:01 amavisd (ch2-avail)
root     22276  0.0  0.0  68836   424 ?        S    17:09   0:00 CRON
root     22289  0.0  0.0  12300   340 ?        Ss   17:09   0:00 /bin/sh -c   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
root     22310  2.0  0.1 561844  2128 ?        D    17:09   4:16 find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +24 ! -execdir fuser -s {} ; -delete
root     22390  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:41   0:15 [kworker/0:0]
www-data 22756  0.0  0.1 382280  4040 ?        S    20:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 22757  0.2  2.1 701700 43256 ?        Sl   20:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 22758  0.1  1.1 399128 23496 ?        S    20:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     24968  0.0  0.1  19764  3396 ?        S    20:36   0:00 dovecot/config
dovecot  24977  0.0  0.1 106348  2260 ?        S    20:36   0:00 dovecot/auth
root     24988  0.0  0.0  15036  1268 ?        S    20:36   0:00 dovecot/ssl-params
root     24989  0.0  0.1 106456  2632 ?        S    20:36   0:00 dovecot/auth -w
root     25081  0.0  0.0  15276  1168 pts/0    R+   20:36   0:00 ps -aux
root     25454  0.0  0.0  68836   444 ?        S    18:39   0:00 CRON
root     25492  0.0  0.0  12300   344 ?        Ss   18:39   0:00 /bin/sh -c   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
root     25715  1.9  0.1 559336  2416 ?        D    18:39   2:16 find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +24 ! -execdir fuser -s {} ; -delete
root     25910  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:28   0:10 [kworker/1:2]
root     27768  0.0  0.0  68836   440 ?        S    18:45   0:00 CRON
root     27779  0.0  0.0  68836   704 ?        S    19:39   0:00 CRON
root     27815  0.0  0.0  12300   620 ?        Ss   19:39   0:00 /bin/sh -c   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
root     27946  1.7 13.2 557884 270676 ?       D    19:39   0:59 find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +24 ! -execdir fuser -s {} ; -delete
www-data 28353  0.0  1.2 552212 26076 ?        Sl   18:47   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     30411  0.0  0.0 1042924  288 ?        Sl   06:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
root     30479  0.0  0.0 186588   408 ?        Sl   06:25   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
amavis   32284  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:59   0:02 [clamscan] <defunct>
```

Comment: I believe they're from cron too.   What's your question?

Answer (score 2):

They seem executed by the php session cleaner cron file, which (in Ubuntu) should be `/etc/cron.d/php5`. You can try disabling this cron entry; however, php session cleaning is a legitimate (and necessary) work that needs to be done.

Maybe you have too many stale session under `/var/lib/php5`; if this is the case, try manually cleaning these stale session files.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I had no idea what was going on or how to explain it. never the less you've provided me with somewhere to start.